# Include backslash in JSON

Tags: python, json, odata

I am trying to post a JSON Payload that includes a single backslash.

The expected JSON is:

```
   {"ID" : "f760caa6-a54b-1eec-bef6-b7292029844f",
    "DeviceID" : "f760caa6-a54b-1eec-bef6-a9fe0249a440",
    "Type" : "FILL_LVL",
    "MeasureTimestamp" : "\/Date(1656951856000+0000)\/",
    "CreationTimestamp" : "\/Date(1656951852000+0000)\/",
    "Value" : "14.000000"}
```

But the the JSON being send is:

```
{"ID": "f760caa6-a54b-1eec-bef6-b7292029844f", 
 "DeviceID": "f760caa6-a54b-1eec-bef6-a9fe0249a440", 
 "Type": "FILL_LVL", 
 "MeasureTimestamp": "\\/Date(1656951856000+0000)\\/", 
 "CreationTimestamp": "\\/Date(1656951852000+0000)\\/", 
 "Value": "14.000000"}
```

Therefore it gets rejected.

My code looks like this:

```
import json                                                                                                   
import pyodata                                                                                                
import requests                                                                                               
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt                                                                               
                                                                                                              
# Connection to on prem SAP via Cloud Integration API                                                         
                                                                                                              
SERVICE_URL = '''XXX'''
HEADER = {'apikey': 'XXX'}                                                       
                                                                                                              
payload = {                                                                                                   
                                                                                                              
    "ID" : "f760caa6-a54b-1eec-bef6-b7292029844f",                                                            
    "DeviceID" : "f760caa6-a54b-1eec-bef6-a9fe0249a440",                                                      
    "Type" : "FILL_LVL",                                                                                      
    "MeasureTimestamp" : "\/Date(1656951856000+0000)\/",                                                      
    "CreationTimestamp" : "\/Date(1656951852000+0000)\/",                                                     
    "Value" : "14.000000"                                                                                     
                                                                                                              
}                                                                                                             
                                                                                                              
session = requests.Session()                                                                                  
session.headers.update(HEADER)                                                                                
response = session.head(SERVICE_URL, headers={'x-csrf-token': 'fetch'})                                       
                                                                                                              
token = response.headers.get('x-csrf-token', '')                                                              
session.headers.update({'x-csrf-token': token})                                                               
x = session.post(SERVICE_URL, data = json.dumps(payload))                                                     
print(x.text)
```

How can I achieve the proper payload formatting?

Update:

I do not actually need to include the backslash character (`\`) but the POST request still fails. Sending it from Postman works fine.

Sending this from Postman works, but returns "The Data Services Request could not be understood due to malformed syntax" when I send it from python using json.dumps():

```
{
"ID": "f760caa6-a54b-1eec-bef6-b7292029848f",
"DeviceID": "f760caa6-a54b-1eec-bef6-a9fe0249a440",
"Type": "FILL_LVL",
"MeasureTimestamp": "/Date(1656951856000+0000)/",
"CreationTimestamp": "/Date(1656951852000+0000)/",
"Value": "14.000000"}
```

When analysing the logs in the SAP Backend both request bodies look identical though...

Comment: What happens if you remove all the  \  from the payload?

Comment: You seem to be confusing the content of the data with its JSON encoding.

Comment: The JSON encoding of a single backslash is `"\\"`.

Comment: Your expected and actual are just two different encodings of the same Python `dict`; the JSON values `"/"` and `"\/"` are equivalent, because there is no special meaning for `/` that requires a backslash.

Comment: Get rid of the backslashes in the definition of `payload`, because *Python* does not remove unnecessary backslashes.

Comment: not sure I understand. My endpoint that I am talking to requires this exact syntax: "\/Date(1656951852000+0000)\/"

Comment: Are you sure your endpoint is receiving these double backslashes, too? I assume this will be correctly decoded on this endpoint to '\/' and the double backslash is only an "issue" in your python script.

Comment: yes the log of my endpoint shows '\\/'

Comment: When you use the JSON Validator under https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/# and you try to validate e.g. the JSON string {"ID": "\small"} you will see that it adds a further backslash, too. So it seems that json.dumps() works according to the JSON specification.

Comment: This fails, too: >>> payload = r'{"ID": "\small"}'
>>> json_object = json.loads(payload) ValueError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 9 (char 8)

Comment: That means your application (Python, Java, Node.js, whatever) in your endpoint will respect the escaping backslash and will resolve it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the problem was very trivial in the end. It was caused by a missing `'content-type': 'application/json'` in the Python script. Sending it with Postman worked because I guess this is automatically set.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a hacky way:

```py
payload = {                                                                                                   
                                                                                                              
    "ID" : "f760caa6-a54b-1eec-bef6-b7292029844f",                                                            
    "DeviceID" : "f760caa6-a54b-1eec-bef6-a9fe0249a440",                                                      
    "Type" : "FILL_LVL",                                                                                      
    "MeasureTimestamp" : "/Date(1656951856000+0000)/",                                                      
    "CreationTimestamp" : "/Date(1656951852000+0000)/",                                                     
    "Value" : "14.000000"                                                                                     
                                                                                                              
}
session = requests.Session()                                                                                  
session.headers.update(HEADER)                                                                                
response = session.head(SERVICE_URL, headers={'x-csrf-token': 'fetch'})                                       
                                                                                                              
token = response.headers.get('x-csrf-token', '')                                                              
session.headers.update({'x-csrf-token': token})                                                               
x = session.post(SERVICE_URL, data = json.dumps(payload).replace('/', r'\/'))                                                     
print(x.text)
```

Comment: sadly this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The phenomenon that `json.dumps(payload)` automatically escapes the backslash in the JSON string is correct (Cf. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159#section-7):

[image]

So it is up to the application in the endpoint to apply the JSON spec and resolve/deserialize/unmarshal the JSON payload correctly.

Comment: I am trying to send to a SAP system. I did some more test. I don't actually need the "\" in the timestamp field so I removed it but I am still getting malformed syntax errors. Sending the payload with postman works, with json.dumps(payload) it does not. Both request bodies look the same on the receiving end but one is giving an error. Confusing...